# Where is the tenants WSO2 Stratos Theme stored?

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

Where is the selected theme for the tenant stored?

I want to get to it manually and change it.

1. Is the theme stored in LDAP?
2. Is it stored in Mysql?
3. Is it stored on the filesystem?

I am talking about the theme that is collected and saved for the tenant. Each tenant has a different theme saved some where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be saved in local registry. Registry location is "/_system/governance/repository/theme".